# MySQL nested Conditional in Update Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out a conditional trigger for an update to a MySQL table. 
The issue is that the update trigger fires off even when the data being entered is the same as the data that was already there. So if I have a column with a row:value set up like this plus_votes:2 if I update with `UPDATE votes SET plus_votes = 2;` even though nothing has really changed the UPDATE trigger still gets fired off. So to prevent all of this I want to add a conditional clause to my trigger like this

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.vote_value <> OLD.vote_value THEN
UPDATE my_other_table
SET plus_votes =
    CASE NEW.vote_value WHEN '1'
        THEN plus_votes + 1
        ELSE plus_votes
    END,
    minus_votes =
    CASE NEW.vote_value WHEN '1'
        THEN minus_votes
        ELSE minus_votes +1
    END
WHERE my_other_table.id=NEW.votes_join_id;
END
```

END

the second half of the issue is that I have CASE condition inside the IF statement. 
Can someone help on this issiu and show how to do nested conditionals inside a TRIGGER?

much appreciated

Comment: completely wrong syntax of `TRIGGER`

Comment: you need to write a simple mysql query not a trigger

Comment: I probably should have included the entire trigger syntax I meant it as as pseudo code. I do appreciate your help and will correct this in future posts or clearly mark it.

Answer (score 0):

although the syntax you have posted is completely wrong, I have figured out what you want try this ( not tested )

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS upd_vote;

DELIMITER $$

  CREATE TRIGGER upd_vote AFTER UPDATE ON `my_other_table`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.vote_value <> OLD.vote_value THEN
      SET 
        NEW.plus_votes = IF(NEW.vote_value=1,OLD.plus_votes+1,OLD.plus_votes),
        NEW.minus_votes = IF(NEW.vote_value=1,OLD.minus_votes,OLD.minus_votes +1 )
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```